# JQuery $.each doesn't iterate through json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to dynamically add html checkboxes for each 'colour' returned from a database, the data type is JSON.

I first make an ajax request to a controller:

```
  $.ajax({
        url: "Home/Colours",
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (colours) {
            $.each(colours.id, function (i, colours) {
                $('#ColourCheck').append("<p><input type='checkbox' id='box" + colours.id + "'value='" + colours.id + "' class='checkbox'>Checkbox " + colours.id + "</p>");
            })
        }
```

The JSON returned is:

```
"[{\"Id\":1,\"Name\":\"Blue\"},{\"Id\":2,\"Name\":\"Red\"},{\"Id\":3,\"Name\":\"Yellow\"},{\"Id\":4,\"Name\":\"Green\"}]"
```

Which when viewed in the browser dev tools looks like this:

[JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvaeD.jpg)

On success I would like to append a new checkbox to '#ColourCheck' as below:

```
<div id="ColourCheck"></div>

     success: function (colours) {
                    $.each(colours.id, function (i, colours) {
                        $('#ColourCheck').append("<p><input type='checkbox' id='box" + colours.id + "'value='" + colours.id + "' class='checkbox'>Checkbox " + colours.id + "</p>");
                    })
```

While I am not receiving an error, when debugging in dev tools I receive an error and the 'iteration' exists as below:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBC6k.jpg)
I would assume I am trying to access the data in the JSON array incorrectly however I am unsure how exactly I should be doing this, I have tried parsing first:

```
jsonObj = jQuery.parseJSON( colours);
```

This made no difference, any advise would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your example data suggests that `colours` is an array, but you are trying to loop over `colours.id`. Have you tried `$.each(colours, function...)`?

Also, variables are case-sensitive: `colours.id` is not the same as `colours.Id`

Comment: truth has been spoken @Tulir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this piece of code solve your problem?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Home/Colours",
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (_colours) {

        _colours.forEach(function(colour){

            $('#ColourCheck').append("<p><input type='checkbox' id='box" + colour.id + "'value='" + colour.id + "' class='checkbox'>Checkbox " + colour.id + "</p>");

        });

    }

});
```

Comment: `dataType: 'json'` tells jQuery to parse the response as JSON, so no need to call `JSON.parse()` yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Tulir, Once I had looped over colours instead of colours.id and changed the case to match what was returned it worked fine. Paulo Queiroz, out of interest I tried your approach as well which worked just as well as the $.each approach. Is there a preferred method for jquery or is either accepted?

Comment: @Danny as you said yourself, they both work therefore they are both valid! Using `array.forEach` means you are using standard JavaScript which might be better as you can use it for web, server (NodeJs) or any non jQuery project.